# How do I achieve the semantics of SwiftUI's StateObject in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a StatefulWidget in Flutter which creates an instance of an object. How can I prevent Flutter creating a new instance every time the state changes?

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not post any code in here I'm going to assume you're doing whatever you're doing inside the `build` method.
If that's the case, then yes, the same object/variable will be created whenever the state rebuilds. To avoid that, you'd need to do the variable creation and assignment outside the build method.

```
class WhateverWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const WhateverWidget({ super.key });

  @override
  State<WhateverWidget> createState() => _WhateverWidgetState();
}

class _WhateverWidgetState extends State<WhateverWidget> {
  final nameOfUser = 'bqubique';
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(color: const Color(0xFFFFE306));
  }
}
```

In this code example, `nameOfUser` variable will not be re-created when the state refreshes.

Please refer to [StatefulWidget class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html)'s official documentation.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: This does make sense. However. If I have a root `StatefulWidget` which itself contains many other `StatefulWidget`s.

How can I achieve the same with one of those child `StatefulWidget` s without having to create the object outside the root widget's `build` and pass it all the way down my tree?

I can create the object in a child `StatefulWidget` outside the `build` method, however that widget itself will be recreated whenever the parent widget's state updates, resulting in two instances of my object, isn't that correct?

In SwiftUI I can solve this by using `@StateObject`.

Comment: If you don't want something else to update unnecessarily then use const in the constructor of that widget.